# How can I implement simple loading image for this line of code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I want to know how or what should be done in implementing loading image before my dialog pop's out? Any gif's will do. what function or line of code should I add in my function?

------------my jquery code:------------

```
 $(".red_img").click(function() {

                });

                $("#red_form").dialog({

                        modal:true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Done": function() {


                            },
                            Cancel: function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                });
                $("#red_form").show(500);
            });
```

Comment: so you want us to read the whole code and give you a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to show ajax loading gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617660/want-to-show-ajax-loading-gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could show your loading image at the beginning of your click event, and then hide the image just before displaying your dialog:

```
// Initially, your loading image must be hidden
$("#your_loading_image").hide();

$(".red_img").click(function() {
    var red_type = $(this).attr("title").trim();

    // Display your loading image here -----------------------------
    $("#your_loading_image").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "get_attributes.php",
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {wtype: red_type},
        success: function(data) {
            var toAppend = '';
            if(typeof data === "object"){
                toAppend += "<tbody>";
                toAppend += "<tr></td><td class=datalabel>Type:</td><td>"+data['type']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Health:</td><td>"+data['health']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Attack:</td><td>"+data['attack']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Defense:</td><td>"+data['defense']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Speed:</td><td>"+data['speed']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Evade:</td><td>"+data['evade']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "<tr><td class=datalabel>Special:</td><td>"+data['special']+"</td></tr>";
                toAppend += "</tbody>";
                $("tbody").remove();
                $("#red_form table").append(toAppend);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#red_form #name").val($(this).attr("alt").trim());

    // Hide your loading image here --------------------------------
    $("#your_loading_image").hide();

    $("#red_form").dialog({
        width:300,
        resizable:false,
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
            "Done": function() {

                if($("#red_form #name").val().trim()==''){
                    alert("Text field cannot be empty.");
                    $("#red_form #name").focus();
                }
                else if($("#red_form #name").val().trim()===$("#blue_name").val().trim()){
                    alert("Name cannot be the same by other player.");
                    $("#red_form #name").focus();
                }
                else {
                    $("#red_name").val($("#red_form #name").val().trim());
                    $("#red_type").val(red_type);
                    $("#red_form").hide(400);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#red_form").show(500);
});
```

where `#your_loading_image` is your loading image, like for example:

```
<img id="your_loading_image" src="your_loading_image_path.gif"/>
```

Comment: Hi mate! you mean you want to display the spinner for 10 sec for example then hide it?

Comment: If so, yes you can by using the function `setInterval`. I think this link might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are seeking solution for a progress Indicator before your pop up dialog, to show the progress of Loading your Popup ,if yes then here is how you can implement this Progress Indicator along with Modal.

**Step 1.**

I have taken a simple Panel ,Inserted an Image in it and "Loading Please wait..." is the text I am trying to display.I have given set the Position of the panel to my desired Location on screen

```
<asp:Panel ID="ProgressIndicatorPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <div id="ProgressDiv" class="progressStyle">
            <ul class="ProgressStyleTable" style="list-style:none;height:60px">
                <li style="position:static;float:left;margin-top:0.5em;margin-left:0.5em">
                    <asp:Image ID="ProgressImage" runat="server" SkinID="ProgressImage" />
                </li>
                <li style="position:static;float:left;margin-top:0.5em;margin-left:0.5em;margin-right:0.5em">
                    <span id="ProgressTextTableCell"> Loading, please wait... </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**Step 2**
As i want to disable the rest of the screen functnality during the Progress Indicator display I have used a modal Dialog as shown below.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Progress_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" BehaviorID="ProgressModalPopupBehaviour"
        PopupControlID="ProgressIndicatorPanel" TargetControlID="DummyDialogButton" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" 
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" Drag="false" DropShadow="true">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

**Step 3**

Now you need to write Javascript function by including this
$("#ProgressImage").show();